# How to add a image to dojo datagrid cell

Tags: image, datagrid, dojo

I can add a image to dojo datagrid cell by adding a class to the cell,but when I double click the cell the images of row that I clicked are lost,so is there a another way to add a image that not being lost.

Answer (score 0):

yes there is,

simply add an

```
<div class="imagediv"></div>
```

as the **value** of your cell and also in your css file, something like that:

```
.imagediv{height:20px;width:20px;background-image:url(/path/to/image.png);}
```

if you need to display an image based on cell values, you should look into the dojo's layout-formatter functions:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html

(search for formatter)